# iphone messaging: how do I show the senders number

Tags: iphone, messages, sms

When I get a message in from someone, and their contact card has multiple numbers associated with them, how do I then show the actual NUMBER that the message was sent from? (Currently it tells me the *contact* name, but not the number *within* that contact)

Answer (score 1):

Click on the circular image on the top in iMessage. It takes you to the contact details. The contact detail in blue is the one which the sender has used to send you the message.

Comment: What if the sender isn't one of my contacts? Then it doesn't show a number at all (see https://i.stack.imgur.com/q0wCQ.png). How do I find the number then?